# Replace all hex sequences with ascii characters

Tags: php, hex, ascii, data-conversion, preg-replace-callback

I'm writing a simple tool to replace all hex in a string with its ascii equivalent.

I'm able to replace content with regex; however, when trying to run pack on the hex it is not converting it to char.

```
$str = '${\\"GL\\x47\\x4c\\x4c\\x53\\"}';
$re = '/(\\\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+)/m';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(\\\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+)/m', function($matches){
    foreach($matches as $match){
        
        return pack("H*",bin2hex($match));} 
}, $str);
print_r($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `bin2hex`? I would simply strip out the \x from the hex representation and use the newly stripped hex string as pack argument:

```
<?php
$str = '${\\"GL\\x47\\x4c\\x4c\\x53\\"}';
$re = '/(\\\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+)/m';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/(\\\\x[0-9a-fA-F]+)/m', function($matches){
    foreach($matches as $match){
        $match = preg_replace("/\\\\x/","",$match);
        return pack("H*",$match);
    } 
}, $str);
print_r($str);
```

### Output

```
${\"GLGLLS\"}
```

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier is useless if there is not `^` or `$` (anchor) metacharacters in the pattern.

Comment: you're right, I merely kept the OP's code for that.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to offer a streamlined/refined version for this hex-to-text conversion task.

Match the full hex sequence, capture only the alphanumeric substring (as `$m[1]`), then replace the fullstring match with the return value from `pack('H*', $m[1])`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v2Dp1))

```
$str = '${\\"GL\\x47\\x4c\\x4c\\x53\\"}';

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/\\\\x([[:xdigit:]]+)/',
         fn($m) => pack('H*', $m[1]),
         $str
     );
//output: ${\"GLGLLS\"}
```

Here is a tool to verify the results (I have no affiliation with the tool): http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/

---

If you have multibyte entities which are derived from multiple hexcodes, here is the adjustment: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LQ6Jt))

```
$str = '${\\"GL\\x47\\x4c\\x4c\\x53\\ and \\xf0\\x9f\\x91\\xa8\\xe2\\x80\\x8d\\xf0\\x9f\\x91\\xa6"}';

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/(?:\\\\x[[:xdigit:]]+)+/',
         fn($m) => pack("H*", str_replace('\\x', '', $m[0])),
         $str
     );
// output: ${\"GLGLLS\ and ‍"}
```