# Strange characters in (invalid) json string from post request (encoding issues)

Tags: php, json, character-encoding, sanitization

I am trying to get data from a post request using the following line :

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

The json string might be like: `{"test" : "test one \xe0 "}`

The problem is when I try to do a `json_decode($data)`, I get `null`. By `var_dump()`ing `$data`, I see some characters like `\xe0  \xe7a`.

The data sent is in utf-8. I use `utf8_decode($data)` as well, but with no luck. Could someone explain what I am missing or how to solve this issue?

I need to convert the invalid json from:

```
$data = '{"test" : "test one \xe0 "}';
```

to:

```
$data = '{"test" : "test one à "}';
```

Comment: This is invalid code.

Comment: @MarkusZeller if you mean the quotes, it is corrected

Comment: What is the expected input format / mime type?

Comment: the one sending the request is using application/json;utf-8. The json when I var_dump data is like  this '{"test" : "test one \xe0 "}' and decoding that using utf8_decode returns null

Comment: Perhaps you should put the complete send code in your question?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I unfortunately don't have access to the code sending the request, I am using soapui to simulate the requests

Comment: I don't know how [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/tools/soapui/) works. How does this relate to the PHP code in your question? Does SoapUI send a request to your API and are you using the code in your question to receive it?

Comment: Perhaps `{"test" : "test one \xe0 "}` is intentional invalid JSON to test your API? How can we tell? What does the documentation say about this test?

Comment: You can check if the JSON is valid. If not, your script should answer with a 400 Bad request or 412 Precondition Failed

Comment: Anyway, the JSON _is_ invalid: https://3v4l.org/MGJvI

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4296045/12763954), `\x` is not allowed in JSON.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I am doing with SOAPUI, Thanks all for your answers. You are right, the json is invalid. Is there a way to manipulate  $data = '{"test" : "test one \xe0 "}' to rather get $data = '{"test" : "test one à "}' ? I will change on the other partner side if they are doing something wrong. For the moment, is it possible to manipulate $data using a php function ?

Comment: If the JSON error is fairly consistent when json decode fails, fallback to string manipulation to replace `/xe0` for example and then attempt to decode again. But doesn't make sense to send JSON if you are going to send invalid JSON.

Comment: yes, I will see with the partner to change that.

Comment: You might be able to use a third party library to parse the incoming JSON differently than `json_decode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutating a json string with string functions will always be something to be done with apprehension because it is generally easy for a false positive replacement to damage the payload.  That said, here is a script to attempt to correct your invalid json string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gbRIs))

```
$json = '{"test" : "test one \xe0, \x270B"}';
    
$json = preg_replace_callback(
           '/\\\\x([[:xdigit:]]+)/',
           fn($m) => sprintf('\u%04s', $m[1]),
           $json
     );
     
echo "\n" . var_export(json_validate($json), true);
echo "\n$json\n";
var_export(json_decode($json));
```

Output:

```
true
{"test" : "test one \u00e0, \u270B"}
(object) array(
   'test' => 'test one à, ✋',
)
```

If this has known flaws, please leave a comment below and I'll endeavor to overcome the issue when I have time.

A related answer of mine: [Replace all hex sequences with ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77688374/2943403)

Comment: This works fine as long as the escaped entity was meant to be the Unicode code-point. If it's meant to be some random undisclosed impossible-to-autodetect single-byte encoding, you'll need to add some `mb_convert_encoding()` to the mix and do a lot of guessing. Of course, the main point is clear: why use a standard in the first place if you aren't going to comply with it?

Comment: Is there a reason that this answer received a no-comment dv and the other answer didn't? Is this just a user popularity contest?

Answer (score 2):

A way to fix your JSON is to replace the invalid `\xNN` sequences with valid `\u00NN` sequences:

```
$data = '{"test" : "test one \xe0 "}';
$val = json_decode(str_replace('\x', '\u00', $data));
echo $val->test;
```

Output:

```
test one à
```

Comment: This does work, but be careful, it won't work when there's a two or three byte hexadecimal code in the original JSON representing a multi-byte character.